# WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for Azure Artifact during Pip install

Tags: python, azure-devops, pip

When I attempt to install a package from our Azure DevOps Artifacts feed, I get the error:

Command:

```
pip install org-test-framework --index-url https://<company_url>/tfs/<orgname>/_packaging/<feedname>/pypi/simple/
```

The keyring prompts for username and password for the site once entered getting the error as
below

Error:

```
WARNING: 401 Error, Credentials not correct for https://<company_url>/tfs/<org name>/_packaging/<feedname>/pypi/simple/org-test-framework/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement org-test-framework (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for org-test-framework
```

Note: Same user and password works when I try in the browser and able to download the package directly from above url, so the issue is not my credentials. Also I have tried with everyone in the team and same issue exist!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use PAT for authenticate as password.

Create a Personal access token with Packaging > Read scope to authenticate into Azure DevOps.

Refer to this official link for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops#manually-configure-authentication

[image]